# Entity not updated after insert and missing child elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, entity-framework-5

It seems entity framework doesn't fetch the last item from the database just after inserting a new record. Instead it appends the object used to insert as the last item of the result set. So the last item is missing with all related (foreign key objects) information which the other items have.

what I'm trying to do is do a insert and pass the entire table to a partial view fired by a Ajax post request

my code in controller  ....

```
    public ActionResult save(MOH_area moh)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.moh_area.Add(moh);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }


        List<MOH_area> mohlist = db.moh_area.Where(x => x.moh_stt == 0).ToList();
        return PartialView("data_grid",mohlist);
    }
```

Comment: It seems as though you might be using a shared context... if so don't, it can cause multiple strange issues... you should be using a unit of work or repository pattern for the dbcontext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your "moh" object has no value set for ID field. Ideally, I would recommend to create new object of MOH_area and copy values except identity. That should solve the problem as I used this solution in past.

Alternatively, you can dispose your "db" context and then reload the same. It might work out for you.

Comment: disposing and re-creating database context solved the problem. Thanx a lot.

but your first solution didn't worked as expected. I created a new object and passed the values as suggested but the same result. The object used to inset contains null for primary key. So what would be the issue?

Comment: Strange, but good to see that solution worked. Just check over the relationships defined. Had they been proper, first one should have worked. :)

Comment: Yes. Strange. it stills adds the newly created object as the last. and also the last item gets the identity field filed just after the insertion with the auto incremented value. 
Just say if i changed some property of the newly created object before fetching the data back from the db, but after db.savechanges(), then the last item has the changed values while the db holds the previous values.

anyway currently going with your 2nd option. thanks for that. But just consider the other method also...